# Do I need to reinstall xrdp?

Tags: xrdp

I would first like to say I'm new to ubuntu. Recently, I had to install xrdp on ubuntu 18.04.5 to allow for rdp from my windows laptop for a school project. I downloaded xrdp manually and I faced the blue screen issue where I would just see a blue screen for a long time after I login before giving an error. So I searched the internet for a solution and I found out about these commands here which is what I used

```
 sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core
 sudo apt-get -y install xserver-xorg-input-all
 sudo apt install xorgxrdp
```

However, I then came upon a post that says this is a dirty fix to solve that issue and that it is recommended to use

```
 sudo apt-get install xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04
```

instead.

Now do I have to reinstall xrdp and install xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04 too or can I just stick with my current setup?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04LTS (Bionic Beaver) became unsupported in April, 2023, Ubuntu 18.04 has passed its End-Of-Life date. Slandard repositories are closed. You should install 22.04 or even 20.04. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/